R mirt package Error "No applicable method for 'itemfit'
I'm using the mirt-package for IRT modeling. As my data is polytomous, I use the GPCM-model. The modeling works fine (except for the warning "data contains response patters with only NAs", which is known). However, when I run itemfit, I get the following error:
Error in UseMethod("itemfit") : 
  no applicable method for 'itemfit' applied to an object of class "c('SingleGroupClass', 'AllModelClass')"

That is surprising, because the documentation of the package says that the function itemfit needs an object of class SingleGroupClass.
I updated R and RStudio, but the error still occurs.
Here is a minimal working example:
library(mirt)

dat <- data.frame(Item1 = c(4,2,4,2,2,3,4,3,3),
                  Item2 = c(4,3,4,3,2,4,3,4,3),
                  Item3 = c(4,1,2,2,1,2,4,3,4),
                  Item4 = c(3,3,4,3,3,4,3,5,3),
                  Item5 = c(4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,2),
                  Item6 = c(3,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3),
                  Item7 = c(3,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,3),
                  Item8 = c(2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,2),
                  Item9 = c(2,2,3,4,5,3,4,4,2),
                  Item10 = c(2,2,2,4,5,4,4,4,3),
                  Item11 = c(4,3,2,1,3,4,4,3,1))

dat.fit <- mirt(dat,1,itemtype='gpcm',verbose=FALSE)
itemfit(dat.fit)

I know that the data frame is too small for real Rasch-analysis, but I don't know how to simulate data and don't want to share my research data at this moment.

What version of mirt are you using?  I'm using 1.43 and I ran your code without an error (1.41 also worked).  The odd thing is that itemfit() isn't a generic - it doesn't dispatch different methods for different classed objects - it just executes its code.  If it's not a version problem, type itemfit (without the attached parentheses) at the command line and hit enter.  It should then show you the namespace of the function at the bottom of the output.  If it is not mirt, then the problem is a conflicting function.  If so, try calling mirt::itemfit() directly.

@DaveArmstrong Thank you so much! I've loaded several other packages for IRT, it must have been a conflicting function. With mirt::itemfit() it work's as it should.
